# if statements and for() loops in a function with structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, struct

I know this is a very novice question but I am having trouble with my if and for() loops in this program. I tried to designate where the issues are, but basically in main() it asks if the user wants to dismiss an employee and then that employee ID. Then in the dismissWorker function, it's supposed to scan the array of worker ID's, find the ID that matches the employee to be fired (badID), and then change that array. In my dismissWorker function I have it printing "HI" just to see if I called it correctly in main (and it does), but it doesn't run through the for() loop. I'm sure it's something simple that I'm doing wrong, but what is it exactly? Also, I don't know what I should have it return to at the end of dismissWorker, so some suggestions would be helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX_ROSTER 10 //roster of employees

typedef struct workerT_struct {
    char name[81]; //employee name
    char title[81]; //employee title
    int empID; //unique ID for employee
    int empStatus; //
    int year100_salary; //before-tax salary, in cents
    int year100_401k; //annual contribution to retirement, in cents
    double taxRate; //fraction used to determine payroll taxes
    int month100_paycheck; //monthly paycheck, in cents
} workerT;

typedef struct companyT_struct {
    char dbaName[81]; //company name
    int EmpActiveTot; //number of active employees
    int EmpOnLeaveTot; //number of employees on unpaid leave
    int year100_salaryTot; //total annual before-tax salaries, in cents
    int year100_401kTot; 
    double year100_taxTot; //total annual payroll tax, in cents
    int month100_paycheckTot; //total of all monthly paychecks for employees
} companyT;

    void initWorkerArray(workerT list[], int siz);
    void prntWorker(workerT list[], int siz, int indx);
    void payWorker (workerT list[], int siz, int indx);
    int dismissWorker (workerT list[], int siz, int badID);

    void initCo(companyT hubCo[], workerT roll [], int sizRoll);
    void doCoBooks(companyT hubCo[], workerT roll[], int sizRoll);
    void printCoBooks(companyT hubCo[]);

int main()
{
    workerT roster[MAX_ROSTER];
    initWorkerArray(roster, MAX_ROSTER);
    payWorker(roster, MAX_ROSTER, 0);

    companyT myCo[1];
    initCo(myCo, roster, 0);
    doCoBooks(myCo, roster, MAX_ROSTER);
    printCoBooks(myCo);
    printf("Would you like to dismiss an existing employee? (yes/no)\n\n");

    //FIXME FIXME FIXME
    char defaultAnswer[4] = "yes";
    char answer[4];
    int badID = 0;
    scanf(" %s", answer);
    while (strcmp(answer,defaultAnswer) == 0) {
        printf("Please give the employee ID:\n");
        scanf(" %d", &badID);
        printf("The employee ID you chose was %d.\n", badID);
        dismissWorker(roster, MAX_ROSTER, 10); //FIXME

        printf("Do you want to dismiss another employee?\n\n");
        scanf(" %s", answer);
        }
    printf("Goodbye!");
    return 0;
}

void initWorkerArray(workerT list[], int siz) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        strcpy(list[0].name, "Buggy, Orson");
        strcpy(list[0].title, "Director/President");
        list[0].empID = 1;
        list[0].empStatus = 1;
        list[0].year100_salary = 12015000;
        list[0].year100_401k = 950000;
        list[0].month100_paycheck = 0;
        list[0].taxRate = 0.45;

        strcpy(list[1].name, "Czechs, Imelda");
        strcpy(list[1].title, "Chief Financial Officer");
        list[1].empID = 2;
        list[1].empStatus = 1;
        list[1].year100_salary = 8020000;
        list[1].year100_401k = 960000;
        list[1].month100_paycheck = 0;
        list[1].taxRate = 0.39;

        strcpy(list[2].name, "Hold, Levon");
        strcpy(list[2].title, "Customer Service");
        list[2].empID = 6;
        list[2].empStatus = -1;
        list[2].year100_salary = 8575000;
        list[2].year100_401k = 1133000;
        list[2].month100_paycheck = 0;
        list[2].taxRate = 0.39;

        strcpy(list[3].name, "Andropov, Picov");
        strcpy(list[3].title, "Shipping Coordinator");
        list[3].empID = 7;
        list[3].empStatus = 1;
        list[3].year100_salary = 4450000;
        list[3].year100_401k = 375000;
        list[3].month100_paycheck = 0;
        list[3].taxRate = 0.31;
        }

    for (i = 4; i < siz; ++i) {
        strcpy(list[i].name, "none");
        strcpy(list[i].title, "none");
        list[i].empID = -1;
        list[i].empStatus = -1;
        list[i].year100_salary = 0;
        list[i].year100_401k = 0;
        list[i].month100_paycheck = 0;
        list[i].taxRate = 0.0;
         }
    return;
    }

void prntWorker(workerT list[], int siz, int indx) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) {
        printf("%s, ", list[i].name);
        printf("%s, ", list[i].title);
        printf("%d, ", list[i].empID);
        printf("%d, ", list[i].empStatus);
        printf("%d, ", list[i].year100_salary);
        printf("%d, ", list[i].year100_401k);
        printf("%lf, ", list[i].taxRate);
        printf("%d ", list[i].month100_paycheck);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    return;
}
void payWorker(workerT list[], int siz, int indx) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) {
        list[i].month100_paycheck = (list[i].year100_salary / 12);
        }
    prntWorker(list, MAX_ROSTER,0);
    return;
}
//FIXME FIXME FIXME
int dismissWorker (workerT list[], int siz, int badID) {
    int i;
    printf("HI");
    for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) { //FIXME 
        if (list[i].empID == badID) {
            printf("HIHIHI");
            list[i].empStatus = -1;
            list[i].month100_paycheck = 0;
            list[i].year100_salary = 0;
    return 1;
    }
        else {
        printf("\nWARNING! empID not found! Cannot dismiss "
               "a non-employee!\n\n");
        return 1;
        }
}
return siz;
}
    void initCo(companyT hubCo[], workerT roll [], int sizRoll) {
        initWorkerArray(roll, sizRoll);
        strcpy(hubCo[0].dbaName, "Dewey, Cheatham, and Howe, Consultants");
        hubCo[0].EmpActiveTot = 3;
        hubCo[0].EmpOnLeaveTot = 0;
        hubCo[0].year100_salaryTot = 0;
        hubCo[0].year100_401kTot = 0;
        hubCo[0].year100_taxTot = 0.0;
        hubCo[0].month100_paycheckTot = 0;
}
void doCoBooks(companyT hubCo[], workerT roll[], int sizRoll) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < sizRoll; ++i) {
            if (roll[i].empStatus == 1) {
                payWorker(roll, MAX_ROSTER, i);
                hubCo[0].year100_salaryTot += roll[i].year100_salary;
                hubCo[0].year100_401kTot += roll[i].year100_401k;
                hubCo[0].year100_taxTot += roll[i].taxRate;
                hubCo[0].month100_paycheckTot += roll[i].month100_paycheck;
            }
    }
}
void printCoBooks(companyT hubCo[]) {
        printf("Name: %s\n", hubCo[0].dbaName);
        printf("Active: %d\n", hubCo[0].EmpActiveTot);
        printf("Leave: %d\n", hubCo[0].EmpOnLeaveTot);
        printf("Salary: %d\n", hubCo[0].year100_salaryTot);
        printf("401k: %d\n", hubCo[0].year100_401kTot);
        printf("Monthly: %d\n", hubCo[0].month100_paycheckTot);
        printf("Tax: %lf\n", hubCo[0].year100_taxTot);
        printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Post a [mcve]! And format/indent properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function `initWorkerArray(workerT list[], int siz)` you initiate four `workerT` objects with `empID` values 1, 2, 6, 7.

Now, in the `main` function, you call `dismissWorker` with `dismissWorker(roster, MAX_ROSTER, 10)`

In the for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) { //FIXME 
    if (list[i].empID == badID) {
        printf("HIHIHI");
        list[i].empStatus = -1;
        list[i].month100_paycheck = 0;
        list[i].year100_salary = 0;
    return 1;
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, the code does run through the for loop, but it can't find the `badID` and exits. You should print a warning or an error message to catch errors, such as these.

Try `dismissWorker(roster, MAX_ROSTER, 7)` to test it. It should work, and use error / warning messages to catch unforeseen circumstances in the code, such as `empID`'s that don't exist in this case. Commonly known as [Defensive Programming](http://www.drdobbs.com/defensive-programming/184401915)

Comment: Thank you, this works! But would you mind giving a tl;dr of why switching from 7 to 10 fixed this? I'm not quite clear on that

Comment: the key is to look at the `initWorkerArray` function, where you initialise four `workerT` objects with parameters `list[0].empID = 1`, `list[1].empID=2`, `list[2].empID=6`, `list[3].empID=7`. To dismiss the worker, you were passing an ID of 10 in `dismissWorker(roster,MAX_ROSTER, 10)`. When the `dismissWorker` function loops through the four `workerT` objects, it doesn't find an `empID` of 10 as per your check `if (list[i].empID == badID)` so skips the block of code within the if brackets. Passing valid values, 1,2,6 or 7, would go through the if block when ID is found

Answer (score 0):

You'll be able to see the error in your logic clearly if you use proper indentation in your code.

```
int dismissWorker (workerT list[], int siz, int badID) {
   int i;
   printf("HI");
   for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) { 
      if (list[i].empID == badID) {
         printf("HIHIHI");
         list[i].empStatus = -1;
         list[i].month100_paycheck = 0;
         list[i].year100_salary = 0;
         return 1;
      }
      else {
         printf("\nWARNING! empID not found! Cannot dismiss "
                "a non-employee!\n\n");
         return 1;
      }
   }
   return siz;
}
```

As you can see, if the ID of the first employee doesn't match the given `badID`, the function will return with the warning. You need to use:

```
// Return 1 for success and 0 for failure, maybe.
int dismissWorker (workerT list[], int siz, int badID) {
   int i;
   printf("HI");
   for (i = 0; i < siz; ++i) { 
      if (list[i].empID == badID) {
         printf("HIHIHI");
         list[i].empStatus = -1;
         list[i].month100_paycheck = 0;
         list[i].year100_salary = 0;
         return 1;
      }
   }

   printf("\nWARNING! empID not found! Cannot dismiss "
          "a non-employee!\n\n");

   return 0;
}
```